# Sending mail from localhost when working on wifi connection

Tags: php, email

What changes I should do in `php.ini` so that I could send mail from localhost.I am using college wifi.

Comment: All ports are opened?

Comment: @which SMTP server you are using?

Comment: I have no idea which smtp server using . Is there any way to know this

Comment: @PK28 you may ask to developer who develop the site in localhost

Comment: i used gmail smtp for sending mail from localhost

Comment: @PK28 you can use PHPMailer class if you want to send mail from localhost, PHPMailer gives you the functionality to send email from Gmail account as well..

Comment: @YadavChetan how to do that , please provide the code .

Comment: @jogesh_pi I just wanted to send simple mail using mail function , dont want to use Phpmailer class . Please just the changes to be done in Php.ini file.

Comment: Oh, it's _college_ wifi everybody.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this and let me know the error after that i will tell what changes you need to do in php.ini

```
<?php
                    error_reporting(0);
            require_once "Mail.php";

            $from="from email"; //enter email of sender
            $to="recepient email"; //enter to email
            $subject="subject";

            $body="content";

            $host="ssl://smtp.gmail.com";
            $port="465";
            $username="your gmail account user name";
            $pwd="your gmail account password";

            $headers = array ('From' => $from,
                            'To' => $to,
                            'Subject' => $subject);

            $headers["Content-Type"] = 'text/html; charset=UTF-8';

            $smtp = Mail::factory('smtp',
                                   array ('host' => $host,
                                             'port' => $port,
                                             'auth' => true,
                                             'username' => $username,
                                             'password' => $pwd));

            //Send Email using pear sned option
            $mail = $smtp->send($to, $headers, $body);

                //If any errors occurs


                  if (@PEAR::isError($mail)) {
                    echo("<p>" . $mail->getMessage() . "</p>");
                  }
                  else {
                       echo("<p>Message successfully sent!</p>");

                  }         

?>
```

if you are using xampp then pear is already installed and you need to change php.ini.

**First of all you need to uncomment the extension=php_openssl.dll into the php.ini file. If you don't find this line into php.ini file then copy it from here and paste it into php.ini and restart your apache server. This is proper solution for following Warning:

Warning : Failed to connect to smtp.gmail.com:465 [SMTP: Failed to connect socket: Connection refused (code: -1, response: )]**

Comment: what is "mail.php" ???

Comment: @PK28 php inbuilt file you dont need to get it

Comment: I am getting errors:                                             Strict Standards: Non-static method Mail::factory() should not be called statically in C:\xampp\htdocs\my.php                               Strict Standards: Non-static method PEAR::isError() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context in C:\xampp\php\pear\Mail\smtp.php on line 365

Comment: @PK28 can you tell me the version of your php?

Comment: i am using PHP Version 5.4.7

Comment: @PK28 now try it and tell me the error and also tell me your xampp server version

Comment: @PK28 and dont forget to enter your mail and password where i written that ok

Comment: Strict Standards: Non-static method Mail::factory() should not be called statically in C:\xampp\htdocs\ex.php 
Strict Standards: Non-static method PEAR::isError() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context in C:\xampp\php\pear\Net\SMTP.php
Strict Standards: Non-static method PEAR::isError() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context in C:\xampp\php\pear\Net\SMTP.php
Strict Standards: Non-static method PEAR::raiseError() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context in C:\xampp\php\pear\Net\SMTP.php

Comment: my Xammp version is: v3.1.0.3.1.0

Comment: i have to search on this error whenever i get it will soon inform you and perhaps  you are using very old xampp version please install new version if possible because in new version pear is installed

Comment: sorry , i mistaken , actually i am using xampp 1.8.1 and it is the latest one

Comment: @PK28 have you tried edited code and this error are only for strict standard you should  check you email account and receiver account mail may sent already

Comment: just now i tried edited code and got this error:  Failed to connect to ssl://smtp.gmail.com:465 [SMTP: Failed to connect socket: Unable to find the socket transport "ssl" - did you forget to enable it when you configured PHP? (code: -1, response: )]

Comment: @PK28 you can try error reporting to E_ALL & ~E_STRICT may it work

Comment: @PK28 ok now go to php.ini file

Comment: @PK28 find `extension=php_openssl.dll` and uncomment it

Comment: i already uncomment what you told in php.ini file still got this above error.

Comment: have you restart apache after uncomment

Comment: its working fine here my friend

Comment: thanks a lot buddy it is working , actually i forgot to restart my apache

Comment: @PK28 good keep going :)

Comment: everything is working fine but there is a little problem , the address which is provided in $from is not showing(what actually this address i wanted to show in delivered message) instead it always shows $username address

Comment: username address and from address should be same

Comment: you think from is who are sending mail right and $username means your gmail user name or email so both are same